# CloudFormation stack "sls-dev",

Tags: aws-serverless

> serverless deploy

Error :
 The serverless deployment bucket "sls-dev-serverlessdeploymentbucket-b27t7pcj7wgb" does not exist. Create it manually if you want to reuse the CloudFormation stack "sls-dev", or delete the stack if it is no longer required.

Comment: do you have a Bucket named "sls-dev-serverlessdeploymentbucket-b27t7pcj7wgb" ?

Comment: try deleting the bucket first via `sls remove -v` then `sls deploy -v`.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you have defined the bucket name it will consider the bucket should exist. Does not seem to be your case since you have this strange name.
2. You may have delete part of your stack manually and now it is not matching. Delete the stack through the cloudformation or serverless command and then deploy it again. This will create your stack as opposed of updating it.
3. I also suggest you to defined a better name for your "service", SLS is not very intuitive.